# creating a link from the controller

Tags: grails

I want to create a link for an action from within the controller.

Link I want is: `http://localhost:8080/myappname/color/show/1`

So I've done this in my controller

```
new ApplicationTagLib().createLink(controller: "color", action: "show", 
 id: 1, absolute: true)
```

This however creates this link: `http://localhost:8080/color/show/1`

Notice that `myappname` is missing. How can I make a complete url?

Comment: Per documentation for createLink, have you defined a grails.serverURL property  in your Config.groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need the `new ApplicationTagLib()` in a controller, you should just be able to use `createLink` or `g.createLink`. And secondly, check your `grails.serverURL` setting in Config.groovy, as it's this that is used when generating absolute links. With recent grails versions you should be able to remove the `grails.serverURL` setting entirely and it'll do the right thing.

Comment: I'm running 2.1.2 so I should switch to 2.2.1 for this and other updates